# Rented a 9 seater Mercedes-Benz GL but: 'There is no such car'

Tags: car-rentals

I have booked on a well-known website a rental car for 2 weeks for 9 people. According to reservation I should get Mercedes-Benz GL. But there is no such 9-seater Mercedes-Benz GL. Should I call the rental company/broker (website) and clarify this? Or is the rental company (or broker) obligated to give me 9-seater as marked on my reservation (must not be Mercedes-Benz GL)?

Comment: What company, what country?  In many places, I would guess a rental company would have no 9-seat vehicles at all.

Comment: There are Mercedes Van's which can be fitted out with seats. In much of Europe 9 seat vans are the norm. And most rental companies have some such, maybe sometimes they can take out the seats if they need a van to transport items.

Comment: It from Budget at Bratislava airport.

Answer (score 6):

We don't have any details of the situation, so I would say that if you require a 9 seat vehicle, I would absolutely contact the rental company and confirm that's what you're booked to receive, because it's far more unpleasant to find out you have a problem when you go to pick up the car.